# How to automatically iterate each column and run query in Redshift psql

Tags: python, amazon-redshift, user-defined-functions, psql

Ok, today I did something really stupid that even my mouse went out of battery because of too many manually copy and paste... I'm looking for some help to avoid doing these manually work again.

I have never used Redshift psql to write UDF nor write python code in redshift psql. But I know it supports us to write python code in UDF, right?

My question is, how to write a method in Redshift psql which can **iterate each column** in a table and **execute this same quer**y for each column:

```
select 'col1' as col_name,
percentile_cont(0.05) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col1) as perct_5,
percentile_cont(0.1) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col1) as perct_10,
percentile_cont(0.25) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col1) as perct_25,
percentile_cont(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col1) as perct_50,
percentile_cont(0.75) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col1) as perct_75,
percentile_cont(0.9) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col1) as perct_90,
percentile_cont(0.95) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col1) as perct_95,
variance(col1) as col_var,
average(col1) as col_avg
from my_table;
```

Finally the output will be a table that contains all the values for each col, each col's values (percentiles, variance, avg) will be in 1 row.

**It has to be in Redshift**, since I tried to connect Redshift through python and read data as pandas dataframe, but the table is huge, 1 hour passed, pandas didn't finish executing the query...

Comment: You cannot do this within redshift. However you can use python externally to first find the list of columns and then generate a sql string from that. Then finally execute that sql on redshift.

Comment: But you can create sub-requests, right? Partition your data, fetch it, treat it locally and keep going on all your partitions.

Answer (score 0):

There is no capability within Amazon Redshift SQL to iterate through columns. Additionally, User-Defined Functions (UDFs) cannot read data from tables.

You would need to write a program that runs outside of Redshift that requests a list of columns and then sends successive SELECT statements against each column.

Or, a simpler version would be to make a spreadsheet with the statement you want, then have it output a similar statement for each column. That could be done with a formula and lots of *Fill Down*. Then, just paste the commands into a Redshift client.